# Open / navigate to HealthKit results graph from another app

Tags: ios, healthkit

Is there any way to open/navigate to HealthKit results graph (Eq. Health -> Body Measurements -> Body Fat Percentage) from another app?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API or URL scheme for opening the Health app from another app. You should [file an Enhancement Request](http://bugreporter.apple.com) with Apple if you'd like to have a way to do this.